# How to find best resemblance between 1 row and the rest of dataframe in R?

Tags: r, similarity, cosine-similarity

How can I find the best resemblance between one particular row and the rest of the rows in a dataframe?

I try to explain what I mean. Take a look at this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(person = 1:5, var1 = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L), var2 = c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L), var3 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("person", 
"var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

How can I find the best resemblance between person 1 (row 1) and the rest of the rows (persons) in the data frame. The output should be something like: person 1 still in row 1 and the rest of the rows in order of best resemblance. The simmilarity algorithm I want to use is cosine or pearson. I tried to solve my problem with functions from the `arules package`, but it didn't match well with my needs.

Any ideas someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is to define the cosine function manually, and apply it on your data frame, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x, y){
  crossprod(x, y)/sqrt(crossprod(x) * crossprod(y))
}

df[c(1, order(sapply(2:nrow(df), function(i) 
                                f1(unlist(df[1,-1]), unlist(df[i, -1]))), 
                                                          decreasing = TRUE)+1),]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    person var1 var2 var3
> 1      1    1    4    5
> 3      3    2    3    4
> 4      4    2    2    3
> 2      2    5    4    4
> 5      5    5    2    1
> ```

Comment: Thanks! nice approach

Answer (score 2):

You could try `cosine` from `lsa`:

```
library('lsa') 
cosine(t(df[-1]))
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.8379571 0.9742160 0.9356015 0.5070926
#[2,] 0.8379571 1.0000000 0.9346460 0.9637388 0.8947540
#[3,] 0.9742160 0.9346460 1.0000000 0.9908302 0.6780635
#[4,] 0.9356015 0.9637388 0.9908302 1.0000000 0.7527727
#[5,] 0.5070926 0.8947540 0.6780635 0.7527727 1.0000000
```

You provide `cosine` with a matrix where each column represents a person (that's why I use `t`) and it calculates all the cosine similarities among them.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I will try this out. The output is not quite what I wanted, because I want to get back the same dataframe with a different row order.

Comment: And I don't need all the similarities between all rows. So lsa:;cosine caculates way too much.

Comment: The function creates all the combinations in a standard way. You can use this output to then format the results back to your original data.frame.